# How to remove attribute on input type to click? Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to remove on click input type attribute. Example:

```
<input type="number" (click)="removeInputModeAtribute()" inputmode="none">

removeInputModeAtribute(){ 
//remove inputmode="none"  
}
```

Comment: Pass in $event.target and then do something like event.removeAttribute(‘inputmode’)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [@AlphaMirage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14983900/alphamirage) said you can use `removeAttribute` function

if you want to remove `inputmode` just pass the element into your function and use `removeAttribute` like:

in your `.ts` file

```
removeEl(el:HTMLInputElement) {
  el.removeAttribute('inputmode');
}
```

and in your `.html`

```
<input type="number" #el (click)="removeEl(el)" inputmode="none">
```

[working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rjx9ar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know angular but you can do this with plain javascript:

```js
function remove(what) {
  alert('You Will Only See This On The First Click!')
  what.removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

```html
<button onclick='remove(this)'>BUTTON</button>
```

***Turns out this is not the answer!***

Comment: I need to remove inputmode="none" ?